# Image is distorted in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox. How should I approach this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to display an image in a div.. According to the image size, I calculate and resize image width and height when the image is displayed in the div. The image is displayed correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Here is the code, and images for clarification.

```
<style>
#DisplayCar{
    position:fixed;
    border:4px solid white;
    left:60%;
    top:15%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F0F0F0;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
}
</style>

<script>
function DC(imgSrc) // DC = Display Car, imgSrc=image src name or path
{
    //alert(imgSrc);
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = imgSrc;

    var oh = newImg.height; // oh=original height
    var ow = newImg.width; // ow=original width


    var rw=(oh/ow).toFixed(2); // rw=ratio width
    var rh=(ow/ow).toFixed(2); // rh=ratio height

    var sw, sh; // sw=set width, sh=set height
    if(rw*700<=700 && rh*700<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*700;
        sh=rw*700;
    }

    else if(rw*600<=700 && rh*600<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*600;
        sh=rw*600;
    }
    else if(rw*500<=700 && rh*500<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*500;
        sh=rw*500;
    }
    else if(rw*400<=700 && rh*400<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*400;
        sh=rw*400;
    }
    else if(rw*300<=700 && rh*300<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*300;
        sh=rw*300;
    }
    else if(rw*200<=700 && rh*200<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*200;
        sh=rw*200;
    }
    else if(rw*100<=700 && rh*100<=700)
    {
        sw=rh*100;
        sh=rw*100;
    }
    else if(rw*50<=800 && rh*50<=800)
    {
        sw=rh*50;
        sh=rw*50;
    }
    else if(rw*25<=800 && rh*25<=800)
    {
        sw=rh*25;
        sh=rw*25;
    }

    document.getElementById('DisplayCar').setAttribute("style","width:" + sw);
    document.getElementById('DisplayCar').style.width=sw +'px';

    document.getElementById('DisplayCar').setAttribute("style","height:" + sh);
    document.getElementById('DisplayCar').style.height=sh +'px';

    document.getElementById("DisplayCar").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("DisplayCar").innerHTML="";
    var data="<img src=carphoto/" + imgSrc + " width='100%' height='100%'>";
    document.getElementById("DisplayCar").innerHTML=data;
}
function FC() // FC = Fade Car, imgSrc=image src name or path
{
    document.getElementById("DisplayCar").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>



<div id="DisplayCar">
</div>



<div onMouseOver="DC('<?php echo $row['Photo1']; ?>')" onMouseOut="FC()" onClick="ClickPIC()" id="PIC" style="width:320px; height:300px; padding:6px; border:2px solid white;">
                                                    <img src="carphoto/<?php echo $row['Photo1']; ?>" onClick="ClickPicture(1)" style="width:100%; height:100%;" alt="gallery thumbnail">
                                                </div>
```

Chrome:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/z1w2k22yye9ivac/Chrome.png

Firefox:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/28ysnru2wrgc5x8/Firefox.png

How should I change my CSS the Chrome to display the image the same as Firefox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#DisplayCar img { height:auto; }` should work